# How do I check if userinput in java contains a component in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
String offensive_words[] =  {<offensive words>};
String userinput = input.next();
for (int i = 0; i < offensive_words.length; i++) {
    if (userinput.contains(offensive_words[i]) {
        System.out.println("Please dont use the " + userinput);
    }
}
```

Am trying to check firstly if user input contains an offensive word listed in my array of offensive word. Then if user input contains such words listed in the array, then print a message saying(Please don't use the ).

Comment: How far have you got so far? What part are you stuck on? Is there some code you can show us?

Comment: by writing the code that does this. the methods equals, contains, ... come to mind. a simple iteration 'll come in handy as well.

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far. Hint: the `main()` method receives an `args` parameter which is an array of `String` -s. Here is a nice beginners tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: that's what am trying

Comment: @TamasRev have checked it, but i dont get

Answer (score 1):

You got a user input. This is a `String`. You can use `String.contains(offensiveWord)` to check if this string contains given string. You can just create a `for-each` loop which will iterate through your list of offensive words and do something if user input contains them.

Also, you can `String.split()` your input and then (in a double `for` loop) check if `String.equalsIgnoreCase(offensiveWord)` returns `true`.

Sample code for you :

```
public static boolean contains(String input, String[] ows) {
  for (String ow : ows) {
    if (input.contains(ow)) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```